# What is the difference of using とき and 時 in this sentence？

Tags: words

I think both words would similarly mean 'when'so I would like to know if there is any nuance between them and why they are written in different forms.

電源を入れた**とき**(160°C設定もしくは180°C設定**時**)にランプが赤く点滅します。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

設定時 is read as せってい**じ** because 時 follows an on-yomi compound. There is no significant difference in meaning, but, as usual, on-yomi words sound more technical and stiff. In this case, I guess the writer simply preferred the shorter expression because it was in the parentheses. In addition, although 電源を入れたとき can be also rephrased as 電源【でんげん】投入【とうにゅう】時【じ】, this may be regarded as a bit too stiff in a documentation targeted at ordinary people these days.